# plot 2D colored based on column value

Tags: r

Running a simple plot, trying to plot two columns of 2D data based on conditional of one column.

```
Table <- read.csv("Del.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
plot(DEL$PAST, DEL$ACTV, col=ifelse(is.na(DEL$PAST), 'blue', 'red'))
dput(DEL, "foo")
```

I see

```
PAST = c(-3.68, NA, NA, 74.67, 147, 
233.47, 371.26, NA, NA, NA, 72.1, 72.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
```

So why plot comes out all red?

Comment: The `NA`s don't get plotted. Where would you put the points??

Comment: Sure enough, I tried to change NA to 0 but failed. This indeed is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the NA's don't plot.

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
DEL <- data.frame(PAST=sample(c(rep(NA,10),1:10),10, replace=T),
                  ACTV=sample(1:10,10))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
# only get non-NA points
with(DEL, plot(PAST,ACTV, main="NA does not plot"))
# can set NA's to 0 - will plot on y-axis
DEL$PAST <- ifelse(is.na(DEL$PAST),0,DEL$PAST)
with(DEL, plot(PAST,ACTV, col=ifelse(PAST==0,"blue","red"), main="NAs set to 0"))
```

[image]